# Why can't plain water be used in dialysis? Why is buffer used?

Tags: proteins

I read that buffer is used in dialysis because usage of water could cause precipitation of proteins but I don't really understand why and how water can cause precipitation of proteins and buffer cannot.

Comment: *I read that buffer is used in dialysis* - where did you read this? The context of a direct quote would be helpful.

Comment: In my teacher's learning materials.